# C++ Перенос нулевых элементов в конец списка

Tags: c++, массивы

Задача: Перенести нулевые элементы в конец списка, не меняя порядок не нулевых. Написал код, но почему-то не работает. Попробовал в online компиляторе на одном работает, при небольшой длине массива. Другие вообще не запускают. Как понял как-то неправильно массив подаю. Подскажите, как надо, в чем дело ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N; // Ввод длины массива
    int j = 0, l;
    int arr[j];
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
        cin >> arr[n]; 
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++) {
        for ( j = 0; j < N - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == 0) {  // начало переноса
                l = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = l;
            }
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        cout << arr[j] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `int arr[j];` что этой строкой хотел сказать?
и у тебя ещё не учтён случай, если два нуля будут подряд стоять

массив вида `[1, 2, 0, 0, 5]`

Comment: Ну изначально объявил массив так, вообще всегда так делаю, и всегда подсвечивается ? или !, но работало, поэтому не обращал внимание( думал из - за начальной длины массива, которая равна 0, может быть). Если не правильно делаю, то скажите, как надо. А на счет двух нулей, думал, в принципе, что они как-бы поменяются, и цикл дальше пойдет, все-равно ведь количество повторений будет равно размеру.

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler  В этом компиляторе пробовал, если сделать массив из 5 и меньше элементов все работает, но попробовав 7, ничего не выдает. Так-же и другие, но они при любых значениях

Comment: начнем с того, что способом:   int j = 0, l;   int arr[j]; вы объявляете массив нулевого размера, используя в качестве размера массива не константное выражение. Две ошибки в одном объявлении...

Comment: Идёте по массиву, встретили 0, дергаете memmove, последний элемент делаете 0 и так далее, чтобы не грузиться в конце, заводите счётчик сдвигов, если текущая позиция равно сайз минус значение счетчика, Вы все сделали

Comment: Все разобрался :) Спустя 20 минут спать решил лечь, пока ложился вспомнил про динамический массив. И вот сегодня попробовал заменив int arr[j]; на  int *arr = new int[N];  и все работает

Comment: Понимаю, что от вас ожидают, что вы будете через цикл делать, но это можно решить в одну строчку через [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну я даже впервые такое вижу, совсем без понятия, что и как с этим работать. Попробую поискать :)

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e14d4392244ad462